# Extra “will” in message from UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

I found a [sentence in Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/$?q=key%3A9be034d9c673d2146554e2c07d3ba425) that contains an extra “will” word:

> When a post is closed with a single community-specific close reason, this **will** message will be displayed publicly above any private guidance.

(The emphasis is mine.)

I just found a sentence and I don’t know the actual context and how to reproduce it in the UI.

Comment: @AdamLear Where exactly is this text shown? In the moderator UI for making custom close reasons?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Yeah, though it looks like it's no longer in production. I assume it was fixed at some point previously, but we don't dump old strings out. I'll verify this next week.

Comment: Found the extra word, is in the process of being removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string with the extra word is fixed.

---

> Superfluous "will"
> Hard to find in the UI
> Now excised from code

Comment: Will the linked sentence be removed from Transifex completely?

Comment: Not normally, no. Old strings are kept in the list for various reasons.

Comment: Yeah, what Mast said. Transifex doesnt get cleaned up for reasons. You'll just have to take my word for it on this one.

Comment: @Yaakov your word is golden, thanks!

Comment: So the next time I found another incorrectly spelled sentence will mean that that sentence may be actually unused anywhere? And in the current question is just a luck that sentence was still used?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ correct. A strings existence in transifex does not mean that it is currently live on the site. Rather, it means that it existed at least for a few minutes on our main branch in `git` and was pushed through automated processes to transifex for translation. That said, we try to catch most of these ahead of time, and most strings that you find in transifex will correspond to strings that are live on the site.